Batch file opens mediaplayer on fullscreen, when I want to open it minimalized
I have a .bat file that opens a .wav file. I want it to open mediaplayer minimized but it keeps opening mediaplayer on full-screen.
This is the code I use:
start /min audio.wav
Is there something wrong with it?
I've tried multiple different ways of making the batch file open mediaplayer minimized. Some didn't do anything, others gave me an error message.
start /min audio.wav
is the only code that even opens mediaplayer.
The code works on other batch files but not on other file types
(I have tested it on .txt and .wav files).
It basically does the same as start audio.wav.

The /min is for the start command itself, not the thing being started. You have to explicitly call mediaplayer and pass it whatever argument it uses to be minimized.

To clarify, you are not making any attempt at opening 'mediaplayer'. All you are doing is trying to open audio.wav in whichever, (if any), application has been configured to handle files with the extension .wav, on a particular computer, for the user running it.
